# Why doesn't cast to NavigableSet throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception, treeset, sortedset

keySet() returns java.util.Set. 
Why doesn't cast to NavigableSet  throw a ClassCastException?
This can be if real Object is a TreeSet with the java.util.Set reference. I can`t understand that.

```
import java.util.*;
class A1{}
public class Main{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         SortedMap nvs=new TreeMap();
         nvs.put(1,"one");
         nvs.put(2,"two");
         nvs.put(3,"three");
         nvs.put(4,"four");
         NavigableSet nss=(NavigableSet)nvs.keySet();
         for(Object ob: nss){
              System.out.print(nvs.get(ob)+", ");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to look at actual code of `TreeMap` (this is from java 1.7):

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return navigableKeySet();
}

public NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet() {
    KeySet<K> nks = navigableKeySet;
    return (nks != null) ? nks : (navigableKeySet = new KeySet(this));
}
```

And here's the `KeySet` class declaration:

```
static final class KeySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements NavigableSet<E> {...}
```

As you can see, `TreeMap#keySet` method returns a type `Set` which is a super interface of `NavigableSet`. And the `Set` reference returned from it points to a `KeySet` instance, as in `navigableKeySet()` method.

And since `KeySet` class implements `NavigableSet`, you can always cast a reference pointing to it's instance to a `NavigableSet` reference.

Just to make sure that you are independent of `keySet()` method implementation you could simply call `navigableKeySet()` method to get `NavigableSet` and avoid the cast

Comment: Probably you may also add that `KeySet` is a `static final class` inside `TreeMap` class, that implements `NavigableSet` interface. This will complete your answer.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov.. Let me re-frame your last statement a little bit.

Comment: Is that really unsafe to cast to NavigableMap?

Comment: @EddieJamsession You mean `NavigableSet`? I don't think that it's unsafe since it seems quite logical to me that we get sorted set (and not unsorted) from a sorted map.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah I meant Set)But SortedSet is another kind of interface)SortedSet is super interface for NS.

Comment: `keySet()` is allowed to return any `Set` subtype it likes.  It just so happens that it returns a `NavigableSet`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know. But do you really think that this is going to change some day?

Comment: Not likely.  But why not just call `navigableKeySet` in the first place?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good point =) I didn't notice it was `public`. Edited the answer to include this advise.

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows that you don't understand polymorphism. Let's use an analogy. You go to a bar, and ask for a beer. And you get a Stella. You didn't ask specifically for a Stella, and the bar didn't make it public that their beers were actually Stella beers, but the fact is that the actual, concrete type of beer you got was a Stella. Since the bar doesn't guarantee that you'll get a Stella when you ask for a beer, you shouldn't rely on it, because a future version of the bar could give you a Jupiler instead., since both Jupiler and Stella are beers.

It's the same with your question. The return type is Set, so it could return any kind of Set. And unless the javadoc guarantees that the method in fact returns a NavigableSet, you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: +1 for this whole stinking stuff. Nice example to explain this ;) Lol, and it's weekend too.

Comment: I don't agree), I understand polimorphism and I do understand that it can be any kind of Set, but I wanted to know which kind)As you can see in my question, I thought that it can be a TreeSet which IS A NavigableSet)and I was partially correct.

Comment: Then why do you think TreeSet is the only possible implementation of the NavigableSet interface? If you understood polymorphism completely, you would know that an interface can have multiple implementations.

Comment: Well, I know only TreeSet therefore I said it can be this implementation)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't through a `ClassCastException` because the returned object IS a `NavigableSet`. You can for example use the getClass() method on the returned object and print it. This class is either `NavigableSet` or a subclass of it.

You can also use a debugger (for example Eclipse) to get the class of an object.

Because the [SortedMap.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet%28%29) specification tells it returns a `Set` object, it may not be safe to cast it to `NavigableSet`. An other, or a change in, implementation may lead your code to through `ClassCastException`.

The compiler can't check for this and as a consequence the check is performed at run-time.

Comment: I edited my answer. Otherwise you'll hit a ClassCastException

Comment: That can be, but java specification tells that it returns java.util.Set.

Comment: Yes but the effective returned class is compatible (equal or descendant) with NavigableSe.